# ReactJS - Function to bulk overwrite nested usestate variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a nested dictionary object with the following structure:

```
  const [fieldErrorMessage, setFieldErrorMessage] = useState({
    signinEmail: {
      show: false,
      message: "Error",
    },
    signinPassword: {
      show: false,
      message: "Error",
    },
    signupEmail: {
      show: false,
      message: "Error",
    },
    signupPassword: {
      show: false,
      message: "Error",
    },
    signupRegistrationToken: {
      show: false,
      message: "Error",
    },
  });
```

I created a function which should take in an array of nested dictionaries (e.g., `signinEmail`, `signinPassword`, ...) and set their value for their `show` key to `false` (without changing the value for the `message` property).

Here is my function:

```
function hideFieldErrors(setter, fieldNameArray) {
  fieldNameArray.forEach((fieldName) => {
    setter((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      fieldName: {
        ...prevState.fieldName,
        show: false,
      },
    }));
  });
}
```

When I call it, the `show` values do not change. Why is that?

I'm calling it via this code:

```
hideFieldErrors(setFieldErrorMessage, [
    "signinEmail",
    "signinPassword",
    "signupEmail",
    "signupPassword",
    "signupRegistrationToken",
  ]);
```

Comment: Could you post a result of `console.log(fieldErrorMessage)`? I see one mistake in your code and want to be sure it's the main reason of your problems. In `setter` you should use `[fieldName]` (computed property name) as now you are setting and setting `fieldName` in a loop.

Comment: This is the console response. You seem to be right as it appeared to have create a new 'fieldname' object.

`fieldName: {show: false}
signinEmail: {show: true, message: 'An email must be specified'}
signinPassword: {show: true, message: 'A password must be specified'}
signupEmail: {show: true, message: 'An email must be specified'}
signupPassword: {show: true, message: 'A password must be specified'}
signupRegistrationToken: {show: true, message: 'Enter a registration token'}
[[Prototype]]: Object`

I'll try your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have used `fieldName` is not working as you expected. variable name(which is a string) should be wrapped with square brackets to make it an accessible property.

Try like below.

```
function hideFieldErrors(setter, fieldNameArray) {
  fieldNameArray.forEach((fieldName) => {
    setter((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [fieldName]: {
        ...prevState[fieldName],
        show: false,
      },
    }));
  });
}
```